# Problem with password reset in React and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux, axios

I'm trying to reset password using React and Redux and there is one problem. I send the post request to API with a new password and token in body (as my server requires). When I do it in Postman everything is okay, but the problem is when I'm trying to send a request from my React application.

This is my response in the browser:
[image]

As you can see, a new password and token are printed correctly, but the data field in the response doesn't read the token. Here is some of my code:

Route from App.js

```
<Route path='/password-reset/:token' component={NewPasswordView} />
```

password.js from actions directiory (Redux):

```
import { RESET_PASSWORD } from './types';
import axios from 'axios';

// RESET PASSWORD
// Set a new password
export const resetPassword = (password, token) => (dispatch) => {

  // Headers
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': "application/json",
    },
  }

  const body = JSON.stringify({ password, token })

  // Post request to API
  axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/password-reset/confirm/', body, config)
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
     dispatch({
      type: RESET_PASSWORD,
      payload: res.data
    })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err.response);
 })
}
```

password.js from reducers directory (Redux):

```
import { RESET_PASSWORD } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case RESET_PASSWORD:
      return (state = action.payload);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

NewPasswordPage.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { resetPassword } from '../actions/password';

class NewPasswordView extends Component {
  state = {  
    password: '',
  }

  static propTypes = {
    resetPassword: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { password } = this.state;
    const token = this.props.match.params.token;

    this.props.resetPassword(password, token)
    console.log(password, token);
  }

  render() { 
    return (  
      <div className="col-md-6 m-auto">
        <div className="card card-body mt-5">
          <h2 className="text-center">New password</h2>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>New password</label>
                <input
                  type="password"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="password"
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  value={this.state.password}
                />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  resetPassword: state.password
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  resetPassword: data => dispatch(resetPassword(data))
})

const NewPasswordPage = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
 )(NewPasswordView);
 
 export default withRouter(NewPasswordPage);
```

Comment: looks like your request is missing a token and redux has absolutely nothing to do with it

Comment: But when I change order and token is first in the request, browser give me the response with token and without password. Have you got any idea what's going on?

Comment: try this: `this.props.resetPassword({password, token})` and `export const resetPassword = (payload)` and `const body = JSON.stringify(payload)`

Comment: Thanks man, it works! Could you explain shortly why it didn't work when I tried to pass two values instead of one object?

Comment: Glad it worked. In short: your function only expects one argument somewhere in between: I didn't really place the whole chain in my head as to the way you have it, but the way redux operates is it takes two arguments: action name string and payload object. I spouse it is somewhere along these lines.